# Why are OpenGL programs sometimes referred to as being implemented in software?

Tags: opengl

I was reading a book on OpenGL programming, and in the **introduction to OpenGL** section, the book said that OpenGL is designed to have the ability to be **implemented in software** if no graphics hardware is available. My argument/question is that isn't the CPU still hardware? The fact that the CPU may not be dedicated to graphics is not entirely relevant, it is still capable of performing such a task.

Comment: From that point of view, literally everything is implemented in hardware, and nothing is implemented in software, because all software needs hardware to run.

Comment: It doesn't say you don't need 'hardware' at all. The *functionality* of graphics hardware can be emulated by a regular CPU, but usually much slower.

Comment: I only take issue with the term software and wanted to get a better idea of why it was used. Maybe "implemented on non-dedicated hardware" could be a healthy replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the author means is, that certain operations on which OpenGL (but also other rendering APIs) do depend on are implemented on GPUs in form of hardwired circuitry. Even on programmable GPUs there are certain functions that are hardwired into the very structure of the silicon of the chip. The whole blending, depth testing and stencil operations for example (this is why reimplementing those operations in a shader causes several orders of magnitude in performance drop). Also things like texture fetch and interpolation are implemented as dedicated hardware on the silicon.

Comment: This makes sense now. I get it. I did not know that. I just thought gpus were faster and better because they could perform flops and they did not have to worry about running the operating system.

Comment: @worlboss: That one made me chuckle: *"I just thought gpus were faster and better because they could perform flops"*. -- This is *NOT* what makes a GPU. "flops" is just an abbreviation for *"FLoating point Operations Per Second"* and that number can be given for any kind of processor. What makes a GPU a GPU is a special hardware architecture that's optimized for the massively parallel identical execution of (simple) programs over large arrays of data, where certain complex operations like texture fetch, visibility tests and blending, are implemented by hardwired circuitry on the silicon.

Answer (score 0):

Well by that logic, you drawing it by hand would also be done in hardware, just a few orders of magnitude slower than a dedicated GPU right?

That's just what the terminology meant, whether or not the GPU is available (or usable). It's not an issue anymore, the speed reduction would be so huge nobody even bothers anymore. You either have the hardware requirements or it won't even run.

Answer (score 0):

I think the wording is somewhat obsolete. What it's trying to say is that OpenGL could be implemented entirely in software running on the CPU, versus requiring specialized hardware.

It made more sense when GPUs consisted of hardware that executed only fixed functions. In that case, "in software" automatically implied that the rendering logic was implemented in software running on the CPU.

These days, where large parts of the graphics pipeline are programmable, the statement does not make much sense anymore. The real distinction is if the rendering runs on the CPU or the GPU. You could say that the rendering is done "in software" in both cases, since both types of processors run code implemented by the programmer. They just have very different performance characteristics, and the technology (language) used to program them is different.

Aside from these technicalities, IMHO the statement is pointless anyway. I can't imagine **any** API that strictly requires dedicated hardware. No matter how you design the API, it can always be implemented in software on a general purpose processor. In that sense, the statement says nothing meaningful at all.